# Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms for core 2.0

Tags: rdlc, reportviewer, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using RDLC reports and generating PDF in MVC. While migrating MVC project to Core 2.0 I observed there is no Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms for core 2.0. Is there any alternative?

Comment: I've a solution here in another question, check this link: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/64777303/9874965](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64777303/9874965)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.V15 not compatible with .NET Core 3.1 - How to show RDLC in WPF Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61673864/microsoft-reportviewer-winforms-v15-not-compatible-with-net-core-3-1-how-to-s)

Answer (score 0):

Please see this thread on GitHub regarding the .NET Core team plans for ReportViewer:

https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1528

That thread mentions a project by Alan Juden that might be useful to you:

https://github.com/alanjuden/MvcReportViewer

Comment: Just for info, the Alan Juden project doesn't work with local report files, only server reports. See https://github.com/alanjuden/MvcReportViewer/issues/83#issuecomment-482998221