# Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.V15 not compatible with .NET Core 3.1 - How to show RDLC in WPF Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, rdlc, reportviewer, wpf-core-3.0

I have wpf core 3.1 project and installed **Microsoft RDLC Report Designer** extention on VS 2019 and created a rdlc file. 
Now I want to show that rdlc in a window but there is not ReportViewer control.
I installed **Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms** v15 package from nuget but it shows error :

"Package 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project."

How can we show a rdlc in wpf core?

Answer (score 1):

Hate to tell you but the answer is: you do not. THere is no known viewer. Please wait until .NET core is no more - which should happen in the unification in .NET 5 towards end of the year.

There is a lot of stuff .NET core has holes in at the moment. You stumbled on one.

Comment: I don't believe .NET 5 will support ReportViewer control either. I can't seem to find any evidence of it. Do you have any links that suggest it might?

Comment: .NET 5 seems no support RDLC

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0-preview-6/

Answer (score 1):

I wanted print A4 paper for invoice and customer contract , so I forgot ssrs and maked it by wpf print capability : 
https://github.com/Abel13/Invoice

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem, and my working solution is to replace:

```
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms
```

with:
[lkosson reportviewercore](https://github.com/lkosson/reportviewercore)

Answer (score 0):

i had the some prblm but i solved it by adding

Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
and
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll
to your app folder
welcome bro